# After migrating to nginx from apache author page is not working in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx

After migrating to nginx from apache author page is not working in wordpress permalink style is default id based please help.

Comment: in local xampp its working fine

Comment: hosted in ubuntu server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried flushing the permalink structure?

> Step 1: In the main menu find "Settings > Permalinks".
>   Step 2: Scroll down if needed and click "Save Changes".
>   Step 3: Rewrite rules and permalinks are flushed.

Comment: Yes done still same issue all other url's are working fine.